# Installing Linux alongside Windows without bootloader in the same SSD

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, boot-loader

I have W11 installed in my SSD (UEFI) and I want to install Linux (Kali) alongside it but without any bootloader (I'm ok with changing the booting OS in the UEFI when I want to go to Linux) (VM is not an option bc I need hardware access not available on the VM). My goal is to maintain W11 as the main OS and boot immediately to it when I use the computer unless I want to use Linux (in that case, I would go into the UEFI and boot to Linux from there) and if possible, easily get rid of the Linux when I no long need it.

There is not much about it on the web, and I'm wondering how disk partitioning and EFIing would be done in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty surprised you say "there's not much on the Web on dual-boot installation of Windows and Linux", because that used to be different … by 1998.

Comment: Well you'll *need* a bootloader: what else do you think loads an operating system?

Comment: Any particular reason why you pick Kali of all possible Linux distros? Seems to be the wrong choice absolutely in this use case.

Comment: Seconding @MarcusMüller. Kali is NOT a desktop distro for beginners, it's a security toolbox for security professionals. A _LOT_ of things are _intentionally_ "broken" for desktop usage as they either are irrelevant or pose a security risk for the intended purpose. Better to run Kali on a ready-made [Virtual Machine](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines). If you want to learn Linux administration skills relevant to Kali, it's based on Debian so dual boot to Debian or one of its derivatives. Get familiar with [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/).

Comment: @MarcusMüller saw that since kernel 3.3.x linux supports booting w/o bootloader. I even can have a boot loader, but I just don't want it to bother me every time I boot into Windows (I know I can set a waiting time for 0 on grub, but don't know how to go to linux when I need it). My pick is kali due to its formatted environment for forensic analysis, which I need to use in my college course (Parrot OS would be an option but its more pentesting orientated and doesn't have so much community support as kali).

Comment: @Peregrino69 My preference would also go to running the distro in a VM (I already do, actually), but I'm limited to hardware usages such as network and audio/video adapters and driver issues with my NVIDIA graphics, which I need in order to do my assessments.

Comment: The documentation very often explains how-to in Kali. If you're running into issues with the VM and can't figure them out, you can always ask :-) If the question's [good](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will get help. The devil's in the details - the more you provide and the more focused the question is, the better answers you get. I'm sure you get I'm not dissing you, just giving a friendly warning... check https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @AlvXI that's a misunderstanding. Something *has* to load the linux kernel into memory, then jump to its beginning. That something is called a bootloader.

Comment: @MarcusMüller not quite true AFAIK. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFISTUB). Booting with EFI requires the motherboard firmware to be much more aware of program executables (PE format - Microsoft EXE) and file system formats (FAT32). As I read it, the kernel can be compiled to look like an EFI boot loader program in itself. The EFI firmware runs this as it would run a boot loader. So with this technique there is no need for a "boot loader" as that functionality has been embedded in the kernel binary.

Comment: @MarcusMüller just to be clear, in that context the thing loading the Linux kernel binary into memory and jumping to an entry point is the motherboard firmware - the BIOS on a lot of hardware. Not a  boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

> There is not much about it on the web, and I'm wondering how disk partitioning and EFIing would be done in this case.

I'm surprised you are not finding much about this on the web. Since you already know the term UEFI, perhaps that was the term that might have found you good results for dual booting.

I'm pretty sure the topic of dual booting come up here on U&L regularly, so despit my searches drawing blanks, this may get closed as duplicate.

---

Disk partitioning is just a matter of shrinking your existing partitions enough to make space for a new one ready to install your second OS. DO NOT attempt to move or shrink your EFI partition. You only need one of those and they are not always safe to move.

There are tools that can do this for you (resizing the file system before shrinking the partition) and some linux installers can help you with that.

---

This type of dual booting was hard when we used "legacy" MBR booting where the motherboard would just load a couple of KB from the start of the disk and run that as a program.

With the switch to UEFI, motherboards now read FAT32 file systems for themselves and can run a PE32 format program (same format as Microsoft EXE) to start the OS. That program is typically the boot loader (even MS Windows has one).

So with UEFI, you can safely install two OS side by side and they just have different boot loaders saved on the same EFI partition. This lets the firmware chose what to boot.

---

Watch out when installing Linux, most distributions have yet to let you fully configure EFI yourself and they like to self configure it.

This means that OS forks can sometimes name their EFI files the same. Eg Mint and Ubuntu had a problem last time I tried.  Kali with Ubuntu might also have a problem.

Since you want Kali with MS windows this risk is pretty low.

---

You also mentioned wanting to do this without a boot loader.  I can't speak for Kali, I don't use it, but it might try to install a boot loader in EFI by default.

If you want, you can experiment with [EFISTUB](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/efi-stub.html).  This lets the kernel act as its own boot loader when using EFI. Arch Linux has a reasonable [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFISTUB) on the topic.

Answer (score -1):

1. Backup the EFI system partition
2. Install Linux
3. Boot into Linux. Using `efibootmgr` set Windows as your default OS. This can be done from inside the EFI setup (e.g. BIOS settings, F2/F8/F11, whatever).

After uninstalling Linux restore the EFI system partition backup or simply restore the `{EFI_SYSTEM_PARTITON}/EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI` file which many distros overwrite.

Proper Linux distributions do not overwrite this file, so to completely delete any installed Linux you can simply delete the `{EFI_SYSTEM_PARTITON}/EFI/Linux_name` directory.